# How do I print Fetch promise value in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch-api

I'm trying to print out the value of Fetch promise, but it shows `undefined` when i console.log it.

Php server responds to this fetch with a jwt token in the body of http when I try it in Postman.

```
 fetch("http://localhost:8001/api/login", {
                        method: 'post',
                        headers: {
                            "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
                       },
                        body: 'username=' + this.state.username + '&password=' + this.state.password
                    })
                        .then(function (responseObject) {
                            console.log('Request succeeded with Response object', responseObject);

                        })
                        .then(function (result){
                            console.log(result);
                        })
                        .catch(function (error) {
                            console.log('Request failed', error);
                        });
                }else{
                    console.log('You must enter username, password.');
                }
```

Comment: your first .then has no return statement, so returns `undefined` ... which is why result in the second .then is undefined. try return `responseObject.text()` or `responseObject.json()` in your first .then

Comment: Solved the problem by addding `return responseObject` to the first. then clause and `console.log(responseObject.text()); to the second .then clause, now my jwt token prints out. Thank you  @Jaro

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use a formatter to log or do something with the data, following is a way of doing it

```
fetch('http://localhost:8001/api/login').then(
function(response) {
  if (response.status !== 200) {
    console.log('Problem in fetching');
    return;
  }
  response.text().then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
})
```

Comment: set `response.text().then` in the lifetime of `response` really works!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to call something like `json()` or `text()` off of `responseObject` and return that result to get it into `result`.

Answer (score 0):

```
            fetch("http://localhost:8001/api/login", {
                method: 'post',
                headers: {
                    "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
               },
                body: 'username=' + this.state.username + '&password=' + this.state.password
            })
                .then(function (responseObject) {
                    console.log('Request succeeded with Response object', responseObject);
                    return responseObject;
                })
                .then(function (result){
                    console.log(result.text());
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log('Request failed', error);
                });
        }else{
            console.log('You must enter username, password.');
        }
```

Solved the problem by addding **return responseObject** to the first .then clause and **console.log(responseObject.text());** to the second .then clause, now my jwt token prints out.

Comment: The first `then` clause receives the promise and returns `.json()` or `.text()`. The second one uses the json response. Using only one `then` clause will return the 'Promise' which is what we don't expect to use.